# i want to keep the text " school of civil engineering,Rgmcet,Nandyal" AS FOOTER WHAT TO DO?

Tags: header-footer

[image]

the picture shows the footer in the ms word 2013. i need to get the same for my document in latex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think `fancyhdr` is the package for you. Look here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers and if you won't be able to do it by yourself, please complete you question with a minimal example of what you tried.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question.

Comment: @Raaja now _this_ is a do-it-for-me question :)

Answer (score 2):

The following code shows the basic principle. You may have to modify the code if you're using a different document class.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[L]{School of Civil Engineering, RGMCET, Nandyal}% Left footer
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}% Right footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule (if needed)
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}% 2pt footer rule

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-20]% Some document text

\end{document}
```